# Sending webcam video to remote PC over WiFi with ffmpeg

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, port, webcam

I am trying to send a webcam live feed from an UpBoard running Ubuntu 16.04 to my Laptop (Windows 10) on the same WiFi network. I want to use the feed as input video for OpenCV so i can run a tracking program on it.

I have managed to get ffmpeg to send the live video with the command:

**ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k -f h264 udp://192.168.1.2:12345**

And can view the live video locally with:

**ffplay udp://192.168.1.2:12345**

But when I try to run the same command to view the video on the laptop it just hangs as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEO69.png)

I have disabled all firewalls and can ping between both machines.

Have tried different ports and IP addresses.

If anyone has any recommendations for how to solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to use "-f mpegts" output format instead "-f h264"

Comment: using "-f mpegts" has worked perfectly thank you for your solution. I noticed a large drop in fps being transferred compared to "-f h264".  Is the reasoning behind "-f h264" not working due to it not being supported by windows?